# How to set custom path to a PDF worker

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, angular-components

I'm using [this](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer) *PDF Viewer Component* in a project with Angular 7, but as it thoroughly explained in the documentation:

> By default the worker is loaded from cdnjs.cloudflare.com.

So, what i'm trying to do, is to load the worker from a local path in my project. But in [this](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer#set-custom-path-to-the-worker) section of the documentation, it isn't explained how exactly to do this.

**What I tried**
I downloaded with `npm install` the `pdfjs-dist` and also found a `pdf.worker.min.js` file, which is in my `shared` folder of my project.

So, in my `main-area.component.ts`:

```
...
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf';

...

ngOnInit() {
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '../assets/pdf.worker.min.js';
    ....
}
```

When the page opens, I can see in my browser's *Network* tab that the local file is found. But in the *Console* tab it says: **Warning: Setting up fake worker.**

Can someone guide me on how to successfully setup a worker? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't tried it but this seems to be the solution: https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues/136#issuecomment-529800162

Comment: Might also help: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/7612#issuecomment-576807171

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topic of how to **set up a custom path for a PDF worker** was also discussed in the following topic on the project page on Github:

https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/issues/504

The worker file, `pdf.worker.js` (or the minified version, `pdf.worker.min.js`), can be found in the `node_modules` project's folder: `node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/`.
`pdfjs-dist` is a dependency of `ng2-pdf-viewer` and it will be installed together with this library.

The recommended solution would be:

1. provide `pdf.worker.min.js` as an angular asset in the `assets` section from `angular.json` file:

   ```
   "architect": {
      "build": {
        "options": {
          "assets": [
            "src/assets",
            {
                "glob": "pdf.worker.min.js",
                "input": "node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/",
                "output": "/assets/pdfjs/"
            }
        ],
        ...
   ```
2. As documented in the readme (https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer#set-custom-path-to-the-worker), use the following in your pdf-components constructor:

   ```
   public constructor() {
     (window as any).pdfWorkerSrc = '/assets/pdfjs/pdf.worker.min.js';
   }
   ```